# clock() returns 0

Tags: c++, clock

When I run my code below I get a value 0, a few times I did get a value for the intAddition. I've tried many suggestions I found online, but have yet to prevail. My classmate showed me how he did his and it was very similar to mine. He was getting small values, 1 to 3, from his program.

Thanks for the help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

clock_t start, end;

void intAddition(int a, int b){
    start = clock();
    a + b;
    end = clock();  
    printf("CPU cycles to execute integer addition operation: %d\n", end-start);
}

void intMult(int a, int b){
    start = clock();
    a * b;
    end = clock();
    printf("CPU cycles to execute integer multiplication operation: %d\n", end-start);
}

void floatAddition(float a, float b){
    start = clock();
    a + b;
    end = clock();
    printf("CPU cycles to execute float addition operation: %d\n", end-start);
}

void floatMult(float a, float b){
    start = clock();
    a * b;
    end = clock();
    printf("CPU cycles to execute float multiplication operation: %d\n", end-start);
}

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    float c,d;

    a = 3, b = 6;
    c = 3.7534, d = 6.85464;

    intAddition(a,b);
    intMult(a,b);
    floatAddition(c,d);
    floatMult(c,d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `clock` returns the CPU time in rather coarse measures (1-100ms increments, typically). Not clock-cycles of the CPU. So, yes, I expect this will be zero every time.

Comment: You should loop the operation to be timed a large number of times. But note that if you just write `a+b`, the compiler will probably optimize it out because it has no effect.

Comment: I just tried looping the operations, but I'm still getting 0.

Comment: @Ugluk How many iterations? Start from 1 mln. at least. To get true number of CPU cycles, you need something like `rdtsc`, not `clock`.

Comment: my compiler alway gives 0 too. I have begun to use the chronos library instead..

Comment: Don't assume that a `clock_t` value can be printed with `%d`. `clock_t` is an implementation-defined arithmetic type. You can convert it to a known type, for example `printf("%ld\n", (long)(end - start));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value returned by `clock()` is of type `clock_t` (an implementation-defined arithmetic type). It represents "implementation’s best approximation to the processor
time used by the program since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related
only to the program invocation" ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.27.2.1).

Given a `clock_t` value, you can determine the number of seconds it represents by multiplying it by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, an implementation-defined macro defined in `<time.h>`. POSIX requires `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to be one million, but it may have different values on different systems.

Note in particular, that the value of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` does *not* necessarily correspond to the actual precision of the `clock()` function.

Depending on the implementation, two successive calls to `clock()` might return the same value if the amount of CPU time consumed is less than the precision of the `clock()` function.  On one system I tested, the resolution of the `clock()` function is 0.01 second; the CPU can execute a *lot* of instructions in that time.

Here's a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(void) {
    long count = 0;
    clock_t c0 = clock(), c1;
    while ((c1 = clock()) == c0) {
        count ++;
    }
    printf("c0 = %ld, c1 = %ld, count = %ld\n",
           (long)c0, (long)c1, count);
    printf("clock_t is a %d-bit ", (int)sizeof (clock_t) * CHAR_BIT);
    if ((clock_t)-1 > (clock_t)0) {
        puts("unsigned integer type");
    }
    else if ((clock_t)1 / 2 == 0) {
        puts("signed integer type");
    }
    else {
        puts("floating-point type");
    }
    printf("CLOCKS_PER_SEC = %ld\n", (long)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

On one system (Linux x86_64), the output is:

```
c0 = 831, c1 = 833, count = 0
clock_t is a 64-bit signed integer type
CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 1000000
```

Apparently on that system the `clock()` function's actual resolution is one or two microseconds, and two successive calls to `clock()` return distinct values.

On another system (Solaris SPARC), the output is:

```
c0 = 0, c1 = 10000, count = 10447
clock_t is a 32-bit signed integer type
CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 1000000
```

On that system, the resolution of the `clock()` function is 0.01 second (10,000 microseconds), and the value returned by `clock()` did not change for several thousand iterations.

There's (at least) one more thing to watch out for.  On a system where `clock_t` is 32 bits, with `CLOCKS_PER_SEC == 1000000`, the value can wrap around after about 72 minutes of CPU time, which could be significant for long-running programs. Consult your system's documentation for the details.

Answer (score 3):

On some compilers clock() measures time in millisecond. Also the compiler is too smart for simple tests, it may skip everything because the result of those operations is not being used.

For example, this loop will probably take less than 1 millisecond (unless debugger is on or optimization is off)

```
int R = 1;
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
start = clock();
for( int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++ ) 
    R = a * b;
printf( "time passed: %ld\n", clock() - start );
```

R is always the same number (6), and R is not even being used. The compiler may skip all the calculations. You have to print R at the end or do something else to fool the compiler to cooperate with the test.

Comment: It's not necessarily in milliseconds. The conversion factor is `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` (which is required to be one million on POSIX systems, but may be different on non-POSIX systems. And your `printf` assumes (as the code in the question does) that `clock_t` is compatible with `int`, which is not guaranteed. See my answer for more information.